# Cannot access RIDE robot framework from other users in same machine

Tags: installation, pip, robotframework

I installed Robotframework RIDE with my user credentials and trying to access that by logging in with the another user in the same machine. when i copy paste the ride.py(available in C:/Python27/Scripts) file from my user to another user i can access RIDE by double clicking the ride.py file, but when i try to access using ride.py through command line i am not able access RIDE showing a error msg as "ride.py is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file ". Installed python for all users and again re installed everything through pip in C:/Users, previously installed in C:/Users/MyUser. While i am trying to re install everything using pip in C:\Users it is showing as "Requirement already satisfied"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that ride.py is not in the %PATH% sys variable:

> "ride.py is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file ".

Usually RIDE lives at C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robotide

You may try to run it with the full path in the command:
`pythonw C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robotide\__init__.py`

You may check if there is `C:\Python27\Scripts\ride.py` and the %PATH% variable for the other users (better to change it a System level).

---

About the error "Requirement already satisfied" from pip, that may be because:
 1. RIDE is correctly installed (but you missed to run it in the first error)
 2. You were calling a different `pip` install

Comment: Hi Helio, in another machine i found that ride.py is available in C:\Python27\Scripts and but in machine only ride.pyc i.e., complied version is available is there any place i miss installaton step

Comment: i checked environment variable path in both the machines they are same and in one machine ride.py is available(in C:\Python27\Scripts) and in other machine only ride.pyc(in C:\Python27\Scripts) is available, as you said ride.py is not availble in the %PATH% i.e, C:\Python27\Scripts i am getting the error so i copied ride.py file from another machine and pasted in my machine(C:\Python27\Scripts), now i am able to access RIDE from command prompt. But only thing i am surprising about is how i miss ride.py file in C:\Python27\Scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, somehow i tried to run the RIDE for all users.

Answer (score 0):

finally got the solution, problem is not with the other users or installation, it is ride.py file which is missing in 'C:\Python27\Scripts' folder i replaced that file and now i am able to access ride.py from command prompt for all users in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory where you have the ride(Python file).
Upon opening the command prompt , for me the default path is C:\Users\etwxxbe.
Copy paste the ride(Python file) in the default path ,here the directory is etwxxbe.

Then use the command C:\Users\etwxxbe>ride.py to open ride.